# Ionic build android Nodejs

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I get this Error when i run

> ionic build android

Error screenshot

[image]

```
C:\Users\Ahmed\IonicProjects\first\firstIonicApp>ionic build android
Running command: "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe"      C:\Users\Ahmed\IonicProjects
\first\firstIonicApp\hooks\after_prepare\010_add_platform_class.js   C:\Users\Ahme
d\IonicProjects\first\firstIonicApp
Running command: "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" C:\Users\Ahmed\IonicProjects
\first\firstIonicApp\hooks\after_prepare\020_remove_sass_from_platforms.js C:\Us
ers\Ahmed\IonicProjects\first\firstIonicApp
Running command: C:\Users\Ahmed\IonicProjects\first\firstIonicApp\platforms\andr
oid\cordova\build.bat
ANT_HOME is set incorrectly or ant could not be located. Please set ANT_HOME.
Built the following apk(s):
```

Also i want to know is it better to bootstrap ionic projects with yeoman?
i already saw couple of tutorials doing that.

Comment: Did you add `%ANT_HOME%\bin` to your PATH?

Answer (score 2):

based on this [link](https://blogs.oracle.com/rajeshthekkadath/entry/installing_ant_on_windows), you need to the perform the following:

1. Download and install [Ant](https://ant.apache.org/bindownload.cgi)
2. Set the ANT_HOME environment variable to the location where Ant was installed (Right Click >>  Properties >> Advanced >> Environment Variables ...)
3. Add **%ANT_HOME%\bin** to your PATH
4. Open a command line and type "ant -version", and check if it is working.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you dont have apache ant installed.go to: http://ant.apache.org/ and installed apache ant then create a ANT_HOME varriable in your system varriables and add your ant location to your PATH varriable